# Unable to get open sessions other than current client in Java websocket.

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, websocket, java-websocket

I'm programming a simple web socket chat application. When I open the socket, I send a message to join the room with a name and the web socket returns the updated room object showing the current users names.

I'm trying to send the updated room with user names to all open connections, so if I open 2 browser tabs, I should see the users added by one tab reflected in the other, however I don't see that. When debugging on the `session.getOpenSessions()` I only ever see a single session. I would expect to also see the connection of the other browser tab.

JS

```
       window.onload = function() {

                var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/chat/roomName');    

                socket.onmessage = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById('message').message.innerHTML = event.data;
                };

                socket.onopen = function(event) {
                    socket.send('{"command":"join", "value":"MyName"}');
                };

            }
```

Web socket code

```
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("roomName") String roomName) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        currentSession = session;
        session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(getRoom(roomName));
    }
```

On load

```
       for (Session session: currentSession.getOpenSessions()){
            try {
                if(session.isOpen() && session.getUserProperties().get("roomName").equals(room.getRoomName())){
                    session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(room);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default websocket creates a new server (Endpoint) for every request from client.so when you are doing session.getOpenSessions() returns the same session.
make the server endpoint singleton .[link](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2017/02/14/websocket-endpoint-as-singleton-ejb/)